# Rails: test code in lib directory with RubyTest with Sublime Text 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext, ruby-test

I would like test code in the lib directory of Rails. I use RubyTest to work in Sublime Text 2. My library is in `lib/my_lib`.

```
module MyLib
    def self.get_zero
        0
    end
end
```

My unit test is in `test/unit/lib/my_lib`

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'my_lib/my_class_to_test'

module MyLib
    class MyClassToTestTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
        def test_zero
            assert_equal(0, MyLib::get_zero)
        end
end
end
```

Unit tests pass when I run them with the command line:

```
rake test:units
```

To save time I can run only my unit test with this command line:

```
ruby -I"lib" test/unit/lib/my_lib/my_class_to_test_test.rb
```

I would like use RubyTest with Sublime Text 2 but when I use it (Maj+Ctrl+R) I obtain error :

```
test/unit/lib/my_lib/my_class_to_test_test.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- my_lib/my_class_to_test (LoadError)
    from test/unit/lib/my_lib/my_class_to_test_test.rb:3
```

How RubyTest could load the lib directory in the path ?

Comment: The file `lib/my_lib/my_class_to_test.rb` exists ?

Comment: Yes, lib/my_lib/my_class_to_test.rb exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file of RubyTest in Sublime Text 2 is here:

> ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/RubyTest/RubyTest.sublime-settings

I added `lib` to the `-I` option in the `ruby_unit_exec` like that:

```
"ruby_unit_exec": "ruby -Ilib:test"`
```

The problem is fixed.